# How to prove a specific function relationship

Tags: functions

I have a function $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f((0,+\infty))=(0,+\infty)$. Let:
$$(f\circ f)(x)=x\cdot f(x),\forall x>0$$
I have already proved that $f$ is a **One-To-One** function and now I want to prove the relationship:
$$\frac{f(f(x))}{f(x)}=f(\frac{f(x)}{x})$$
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is injective and $f((0,\infty))=(0,\infty),$ then $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is bijective, hence for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ there exists a $y\in(0,\infty)$ such that $x=f(y).$ Now, $$\frac{f(f(x))}{f(x)}=x=f(y)=f\left(\frac{f(f(y))}{f(y)}\right)=f\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right).$$